# Code keeps showing "EOFError: Ran out of input" and "UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'."

Tags: python

Im trying to run this code but it keeps showing this error, " EOFError: Ran out of input", can someone help me out?

Code

```
model_path = EXPERIMENT_ARGS['model_path']
ckpt = torch.load(model_path, map_location='cpu')
opts = ckpt['opts']
# pprint.pprint(opts)  # Display full options used
# update the training options
opts['checkpoint_path'] = model_path
opts= Namespace(**opts)
net = pSp(opts)
net.eval()
net.cuda()
print('Model successfully loaded!')
```

Traceback

```
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-12a54160f322> in <module>()
      1 #@title
      2 model_path = EXPERIMENT_ARGS['model_path']
----> 3 ckpt = torch.load(model_path, map_location='cpu')
      4 opts = ckpt['opts']
      5 # pprint.pprint(opts)  # Display full options used

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in _legacy_load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    762             "functionality.")
    763 
--> 764     magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
    765     if magic_number != MAGIC_NUMBER:
    766         raise RuntimeError("Invalid magic number; corrupt file?")

EOFError: Ran out of input
```

### Update 1

Im now having a different problem, but i know where it's coming from. From before you can see the code, but the line "ckpt = torch.load(model_path, map_location='cpu')" seems to have a problem reading the file. I'm not sure if it is corrupted or i am doing something wrong. Here is the new error code and file.

```
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-698ee78d7482> in <module>()
      1 model_path = EXPERIMENT_ARGS['model_path']
----> 2 ckpt = torch.load(model_path, map_location='cpu')
      3 opts = ckpt['opts']
      4 # pprint.pprint(opts)  # Display full options used
      5 # update the training options

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    593                     return torch.jit.load(opened_file)
    594                 return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
--> 595         return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    596 
    597 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in _legacy_load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    762             "functionality.")
    763 
--> 764     magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
    765     if magic_number != MAGIC_NUMBER:
    766         raise RuntimeError("Invalid magic number; corrupt file?")

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'.
```

File

`<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Google Drive - Quota exceeded</title><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><style nonce="FJRGcYUexv2A+x96em+/Uw">/* Copyright 2022 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. */`

The problem is with the second line of code, I dont think the other  ones are wrong, what should i do?

### Update 2

Feeling a little stupid, but i had to just redownload the script again since the file wasnt working. Should've been the first thing i tried.

Comment: Probably something wrong with the format of the input file `model_path`...

Comment: i actually found the problem, it was with one of the files. it says invalid input key "<", which is the beginning part of the code, and if i delete that key or change it, it will show something else. Ill show it in my post.